# Why is the concurrent API limit not present in the Limits data end point?

Tags: governorlimits, data, limits

Looking at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm, I am not able to associate anything with the Concurrent API requests.

Why is this limit not listed in the limits end point?

Comment: For Developer Edition and Trial orgs is 5, For production orgs and Sandboxes is 25(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `Concurrent API Request Limits` is not a rolling limit for `24 hours` or `per hour`. Its a runtime limit.

i.e. in that particular instance of time, if there are more number of API requests coming in, then salesforce will reject those requests.